# Find the maximum number of flags that can be set on mountain peaks

Tags: java, arrays, approximation

I worked with a Codility problem provided below,

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.

A peak is an array element which is larger than its neighbours. More precisely, `it is an index P such that 0 < P < N − 1 and A[P − 1] < A[P] > A[P + 1]`.

```
For example, the following array A:

    A[0] = 1
    A[1] = 5
    A[2] = 3
    A[3] = 4
    A[4] = 3
    A[5] = 4
    A[6] = 1
    A[7] = 2
    A[8] = 3
    A[9] = 4
    A[10] = 6
    A[11] = 2
```

has exactly four peaks: elements 1, 3, 5 and 10.

You are going on a trip to a range of mountains whose relative heights are represented by array A, as shown in a figure below. You have to choose how many flags you should take with you. The goal is to set the maximum number of flags on the peaks, according to certain rules.

Flags can only be set on peaks. What's more, if you take K flags, then the distance between any two flags should be greater than or equal to K. The distance between indices P and Q is the absolute value |P − Q|.

For example, given the mountain range represented by array A, above, with N = 12, if you take:

two flags, you can set them on peaks 1 and 5;
three flags, you can set them on peaks 1, 5 and 10;
four flags, you can set only three flags, on peaks 1, 5 and 10.
You can, therefore, set a maximum of three flags in this case.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the maximum number of flags that can be set on the peaks of the array.

For example, the following array A:

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 5
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 2
A[8] = 3
A[9] = 4
A[10] = 6
A[11] = 2
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Assume that:

```
N is an integer within the range [1..400,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000].
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

I walk through the solution provided below,

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {

        int N = A.length;

        /*
         * P =  [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -1]
         * */
        int[] P = nextPeak(A);

        int i = 1;
        int result = 0;

        while ((i - 1) * i <= N) {

            int index = 0;
            int flags = 0;

            while (index < N && flags < i) {

                /*
                 * P =  [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -1]
                 * */
                index = P[index];

                if (index == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                flags += 1;
                index += i;
            }

            /*
             * maximize the number of flags for the whole segment
             * */
            result = Math.max(result, flags);
            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }


    /*
     * A = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, -1]
     * */
    public static int[] nextPeak(int[] P) {

        int N = P.length;

        ArrayList<Integer> peaks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 1; i < P.length - 1; i++) {

            if (P[i] > P[i - 1] && P[i] > P[i + 1]) {
                peaks.add(i);
            }
        }

        int[] A = new int[N];
        A[N - 1] = -1;


        for (int i = N - 2; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (peaks.contains(i)) {
                A[i] = i;
            } else {
                A[i] = A[i + 1];
            }
        }

        return A;
    }
```

Generally, I understand the computation but fail to see where do we meet the condition `if you take K flags, then the distance between any two flags should be greater than or equal to K`.

I imagine this is inside the `while` condition of `(i-1)*i <= N` but unable to comprehend it properly. Would anyone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: If you want to set K Flags with a distance of K than the total distance would be (K-1)*K. And therefor it makes only sense to check while (K-1)*K <= N. The loop uses i instead of K and it checks how many flags can be set for one specific i. With the max() function it keeps the best result before it checks the next i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is `index += i;` combined with the condition `flags < i` in the `while` loop.
They work the solution in reverse: walking K steps at a time, insert at most K flags.